# Django & mypy: ValuesQuerySet type hint

Tags: python, django, stub, mypy

What type hint to use for a function which returns a queryset like the one below?

```
def _get_cars_for_validation(filter_: dict) -> QuerySet:
    return (
        Car.objects.filter(**filter_)
        .values("id", "brand", "engine")
        .order_by("id")
    )
```

`mypy` returns an error

> Incompatible return value type (got "ValuesQuerySet[Car,
>   TypedDict({'id': int, 'brand': str, 'engine': str})]",
>   expected "QuerySet[Any]")

I would use `ValuesQuerySet` but [it was removed in Django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.9/#miscellaneous). `ValuesQuerySet` reported by `mypy` comes from [3rd party lib `django-stubs`](https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs/blob/6b3b6be3c139d1165925ee02e39b8ea3135e368f/django-stubs/db/models/query.pyi) (and I am unable to import it; is it actually possible?).

Comment: What is Django version you are currently using in this project

Comment: The project uses Django 3.

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same problem, and I found a solution in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs/issues/144):

```
import typing

if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
    from django.db.models.query import ValuesQuerySet

def _get_cars_for_validation(filter_: dict) -> 'ValuesQuerySet[Car, int]':
    return (
        Car.objects.filter(**filter_)
        .values("id", "brand", "engine")
        .order_by("id")
    )
```

The `if typing.TYPE_CHECKING` prevents the `ImportError` when you run the program, because the nonexistent `ValuesQuerySet` is only imported during the mypy check.
Also note that the annotation has to be a string: `'ValuesQuerySet[Car, int]'`.

The second argument to `'ValuesQuerySet[Car, int]'` is a mystery to me; the OP of the issue used `int` "and it worked", in my case I tried a few other types, and all of them worked too; you may just as well use `Any`, I suppose.

You can use [`reveal_type()`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#reveal-type) to inspect the type of the variable yourself.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and plan to annotate with # type: ignore considering how hacky this ends up being.

Answer (score 2):

You can also cast to `QuerySet`:

```py
from typing import cast

from django.db.models import QuerySet

return (
        cast(QuerySet, Car.objects.filter(**filter_))
        .values("id", "brand", "engine")
        .order_by("id")
    )
```